# iPhone Safari cannot open page because of "Too many redirections"

Tags: redirect, safari, mobile-safari

Here is the Error link
https://briquetonline.com/mypage

For this page if I am not login it will redirect to https://briquetonline.com/mypage/login (Only 1 redirect)
and it's working fine for all desktop browser including all android devices except iphone safari on both real and emulator devices.

I've followed the guide to clear the website data (Setting -> Safari -> Advanced -> Website Data ) and "Remove all website Data"

I've also disable "Prevent Cross-site Tracking" on Safari Setting as well, but I still got the "Too many redirections" Error.

Could you please tell me Is it code error or Safari problem? If it's the safari problem could you please tell me more how can I fix it?

Comment: Did you find a solution? I'm stuck with same problem

Comment: Hi, do you found the solution? I also try with same suggestion in browser. I try many different device but still cannot find any solution.